# jQuery Maximage not allowing other images to load in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few Drupal websites that are using `Maximage.js` for my slideshows. One repeating issue I have is calling the javascript to work. If I use the traditional jQuery`(document).ready(function($)` everything works fine except for I.E. 8. The problem is, it seems that once the javascript for the slideshow loads, no other images load after that, so I'm left with a page that is missing background images as well as regular images.

To solve this I changed it to `jQuery(window).load(function($)` and that seemed to force everything to load before the slideshow.

My main issue with this method is it makes loading the homepage look funky..does anyone know Why this might be happening? or a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: Most likely the preloading used by Maximage.js is incorrectly handling cached images, or isn't preloading them before trying to interact with them.